# No module named "config" error in Flask restful

Tags: python, rest, flask, flask-restful

I created a virtual environment

`conda create -p my_env python=3.5`

then I activated it

`activate %cd%\my_env`

and I installed some packages, among which flask_restful

`conda install -c anaconda numpy` (https://anaconda.org/anaconda/numpy)

`conda install -c anaconda pandas` (https://anaconda.org/anaconda/pandas)

`conda install -c conda-forge time` (https://anaconda.org/conda-forge/time)

`conda install -c anaconda flask` (https://anaconda.org/anaconda/flask)

`conda install -c anaconda flask-wtf` (https://anaconda.org/anaconda/flask-wtf)

`conda install -c conda-forge cassandra-driver` (https://anaconda.org/conda-forge/cassandra-driver)

`conda instal -c conda-forge flask-restful` (https://anaconda.org/conda-forge/flask-restful)

And then I simply tried to make a flask web api. However, when I write (even in an empty script)

`from flask_restful import Resource, Api`

I always get the same error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Me\Desktop\Myfolders\my_env\lib\site-packages\flask\_compat.py", line 33, in reraise
    raise value
  File "C:\Users\Me\Desktop\Myfolders\run.py", line 3, in <module>
    from flask_restful import Api
  File "C:\Users\Me\Desktop\Myfolders\my_env\lib\site-packages\flask_restful\__init__.py", line 21, in <module>
    import config
ImportError: No module named 'config'
```

So I went and had a look at the actual script `__init__.py` in the above directory, and indeed it does import `config`, however, in the folder "flask_restful" there is no file called config, nor it appears to be imported in any other script.

[image: directory]

What's the problem?

**Edit - More details regarding __init__.py**

This are the first lines of the script `__init__.py` that I have:

```
from __future__ import absolute_import
import difflib
from functools import wraps, partial
import re
from flask import request, url_for, current_app
from flask import abort as original_flask_abort
from flask import make_response as original_flask_make_response
from flask.views import MethodView
from flask.signals import got_request_exception
from werkzeug.datastructures import Headers
from werkzeug.exceptions import HTTPException, MethodNotAllowed, NotFound, NotAcceptable, InternalServerError
from werkzeug.http import HTTP_STATUS_CODES
from werkzeug.wrappers import Response as ResponseBase
from flask_restful.utils import http_status_message, unpack, OrderedDict
from flask_restful.representations.json import output_json
import sys
from flask.helpers import _endpoint_from_view_func
from types import MethodType
import operator
from collections import Mapping
import config


__all__ = ('Api', 'Resource', 'marshal', 'marshal_with', 'marshal_with_field', 'abort')


def abort(http_status_code, **kwargs):
    """Raise a HTTPException for the given http_status_code. Attach any keyword
    arguments to the exception for later processing.
    """
    #noinspection PyUnresolvedReferences
    try:
        original_flask_abort(http_status_code)
    except HTTPException as e:
        if len(kwargs):
            e.data = kwargs
        raise

DEFAULT_REPRESENTATIONS = [('application/json', output_json)]
```

Should I just delete it? It is not used within the script.

**Edit 2: Version of flask-restful**

I am not sure how to include the version of my `flask-restful`, however, if I open the script `__version__.py` I find the following code:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

__version__ = '0.3.6'
```

Comment: I don't see any config import in [__init__.py#L21](https://github.com/flask-restful/flask-restful/blob/master/flask_restful/__init__.py#L21)

Comment: @RajaSimon I just posted what the beginning of `__init__.py` looks like. Is that the only difference between mine and yours? Also, thanks for answering. Is there a way for us to confront our scripts here on stackoverflow?

Comment: @RajaSimon thanks for the github, I didn't see that!

Comment: Can you add the `flask-restful` version in your question...

Comment: @RajaSimon I added an edit

Comment: What's your `pip freeze` shows ?